# What is the proper way of running a Spark application on YARN using Oozie (with Hue)?

Tags: apache-spark, cloudera, hadoop-yarn, oozie, hue

I have written an application in Scala that uses Spark.
The application consists of two modules - the `App` module which contains classes with different logic, and the `Env` module which contains environment and system initialization code, as well as utility functions.
The entry point is located in `Env`, and after initialization, it creates a class in `App` (according to `args`, using `Class.forName`) and the logic is executed.
The modules are exported into 2 different JARs (namely, `env.jar` and `app.jar`).

When I run the application locally, it executes well. The next step is to deploy the application to my servers. I use Cloudera's CDH 5.4.

I used Hue to create a new Oozie workflow with a Spark task with the following parameters:

- Spark Master: `yarn`
- Mode: `cluster`
- App name: `myApp`
- Jars/py files: `lib/env.jar,lib/app.jar`
- Main class: `env.Main` (in `Env` module)
- Arguments: `app.AggBlock1Task`

I then placed the 2 JARs inside the `lib` folder in the workflow's folder (`/user/hue/oozie/workspaces/hue-oozie-1439807802.48`).

When I run the workflow, it throws a `FileNotFoundException` and the application does not execute:

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: File file:/cloudera/yarn/nm/usercache/danny/appcache/application_1439823995861_0029/container_1439823995861_0029_01_000001/lib/app.jar,lib/env.jar does not exist
```

However, when I leave the Spark master and mode parameters empty, it all works properly, but when I check `spark.master` programmatically it is set to `local[*]` and not `yarn`. Also, when observing the logs, I encountered this under Oozie Spark action configuration:

```
--master
null
--name
myApp
--class
env.Main
--verbose
lib/env.jar,lib/app.jar
app.AggBlock1Task
```

I assume I'm not doing it right - not setting Spark master and mode parameters and running the application with `spark.master` set to `local[*]`. As far as I understand, creating a `SparkConf` object within the application should set the `spark.master` property to whatever I specify in Oozie (in this case `yarn`) but it just doesn't work when I do that..

Is there something I'm doing wrong or missing?
Any help will be much appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I managed to solve the problem by putting the two JARs in the user directory `/user/danny/app/` and specifying the `Jar/py files` parameter as `${nameNode}/user/danny/app/env.jar`. Running it caused a `ClassNotFoundException` to be thrown, even though the JAR was located at the same folder in HDFS. To work around that, I had to go to the settings and add the following to the options list: `--jars ${nameNode}/user/danny/app/app.jar`. This way the `App` module is referenced as well and the application runs successfully.

Comment: Nice find, this is tricky, will look at adding better help in the UI!